# How to declare associations in a Ruby on Rails model associated to itself?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, model-associations

In my Ruby on Rails app, I have an Idea model with a father_id attribute.
The model definition declares the following associations :

```
class Idea < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :father, :class_name => "Idea", :foreign_key => "idea_id"
    has_many :children, :class_name => "Idea", :foreign_key => "father_id", :dependent => :destroy
```

I think I got them wrong because when I use the rails console, I can call the children of an idea but not its father. For example :

```
irb(main):008:0> i = Idea.find(75)
=> #<Idea id: 75, father_id: 66>

irb(main):009:0> i.children
=> [#<Idea id: 98, father_id: 75>, #<Idea id: 99, father_id: 75>]
```

which means that calling the children through the associations works fine.
But calling the father returns nil :

```
irb(main):010:0> i.father
=> nil
```

although there is an idea with id = 66.

I am clearly unsure of the right way to use the :foreign_key in associations linking a model to itself. Would someone please have tips ?

Comment: You could take a look at [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry). It seems that it has the features you want.

Comment: Just took a look. Thank you for the suggestion, it does. I will try it as I could really be using some of its features (e.g. subtrees, subtrees to a certain depth, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the `:foreign_key => "idea_id"` on the `belongs_to`:

```
belongs_to :father, :class_name => "Idea"
has_many :children, :class_name => "Idea", :foreign_key => "father_id", :dependent => :destroy
```

(You could change it to `"father_id"`, which is what you want, but that’s the default so there’s really no need to specify it).

Comment: Thank you very much Andrew, it works now. I'd love to fully understand the use of `:foreign_key` in that kind of context, actually ! 1. I realize why it did not work with `belongs_to :father, :class_name => "Idea", :foreign_key => "idea_id"`, because in a given record, it is the attribute `father_id` and not `idea_id` the one that refers to the record that it belongs to (i.e. its father). 2. I also understand, as you say, the fact that rails defaults the foreign key to `father_id`, based on `:father` following `belongs_to`.

Comment: Now, 3. I am wondering if I really get it right when I declare `has_many :children, :class_name => "Idea", :foreign_key => "father_id", :dependent => :destroy`. Is it really needed and correct to have `:foreign_key => "father_id"` ? Do you always have the same foreign key on both ends of such a `belongs_to and has_many` association ?

Comment: If you know of a way for me to give you credit for your help without having a reputation above 15, please let me know, I'll be happy to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove both foreign_key specifications

```
belongs_to :father, :class_name => "Idea"
has_many :children, :class_name => "Idea", :dependent => :destroy
```

And, make sure you have a migration which adds `father_id` in `ideas`.

Comment: Thanks @Ashish. `father_id` was defined indeed in the migration that created the ideas table. Your suggestion to remove both `:foreign_key' specifications looks like an answer to my comments to @Andrew 's answer... Would you be able to explain in what kind of situations the foreign key needs to be specified ?